# Alternative of asp update panel in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I am basically a .net developer and very new to jsf, so it may be a very basic question and its answer may be very obvious, sorry for that.

I have developed a jsf application. where I have a form with personal data and a link button for some other functionality. When personal data is filled and displayed on jsf, I click on that link button, which calls some bean functionality. but my previous data of 'personal data' is loss.          OR      I can say that on postback data of my jsf page losts/resets.

Edit: Here goes my jsf and bean

```
<f:view> 
<h:form> 
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}"/>
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.getInfo}/>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.fullName}"/> 
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.contactNo}"/> 
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.changeContactNo"}/> 
</h:form> 
</f:view>
```

and myBean:

```
 public class myBean
    {
        private String name;
        private String fullName;
        private String contactNo;

        public myBean()
        {
        }

        public String getInfo()
        {
            String endName = getname();
            fullName = "Prof"+ endName;
            contactNo = "12345";
        }

        public String changeContactNo()
        {
            contactNo = "999999";
        }
    }
```

Now when I click on command button it sets the full name and contact no.
But when I click on Link button it should only change the contact no. but "fullName" value
of outputText is lost.

Comment: Could be scope issue. Please post some code of the backing bean and the webpage so that others can narrow down to the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to look for **Bean Scopes** currently you are probably using **request scoped** beans try switching to **view scoped** or **session scoped**

**Edit:** And you should have corresponding data fields related with html form elements in your backing bean with getters and setters.

Comment: my bean is of session scoped, is there anything like update panel in jsf? thanks for considering my question.

Comment: do you have corresponding data fields related with html form elements in your backing bean with getters and setters?

Comment: Yea i do have getters and setters for corresponding data fields.. so that its setting the values for first command button action. (sorry am unable to post my code with line breaks :| )

Comment: can you post your code by editing your question? can you confirm by debugging if pressing the button hits the backing bean?